# Python sort using key : possible to parallelize?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, parallel-processing

Let's say I have a list of lists `my_list`.
I want to sort `my_list` using some operation on each element of `my_list` which is also a list (let us call them `inner_list`).

```
def fun(inner_list):
    # do some calculation on inner list
    time.sleep(1)  # simulate expensive operation
    return cost


sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda inner_list: fun(inner_list))
```

- Since `fun` is expensive in terms of time, is there any way to calculate the cost using `fun` in parallel? If yes, would `threading` be a good choice? AFAIK due to GIL `threading` can't actually do stuff in parallel. However, if the expensive nature is due to iterating over items of a long list, can `threading` help?
- What other ways can I speed this up?

Note: I am limited to python 2.7.

**Edit** : Added details

Here is the exact code. `fun` is an abstraction for `get_delay`. `graph` is a networkx graph with each link `(u, v)` having some value for `delay`. Basically, I am iterating over all edges on the path and calculating the cumulative delay. The `path` is a list of nodes. For example if `path = [1, 2, 3, 4]` then the `(u, v)` links would be `[ (1, 2) , (2, 3), (3, 4)]`.

```
def get_delay(path):
    return sum([float(graph.get_edge_data(u, v)['delay']) for u, v in zip(path[:-1], path[1:])])
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what `fun` does and what its output is (perhaps even post its code)? The best solution could well depend on the exact nature of `fun` (to what extent its affected by the GIL, how large its output is, that sort of thing).

Comment: Added details. Please see edit.

Comment: `fun` gets called once for each inner list. And you're correct that `threading` won't help here. Can we assume that each `inner_list` in `my_list` is unique?

Comment: Yes. Each ``inner_list`` represents a unique path.

Comment: What is the type returned by `graph.get_edge_data(u, v)['delay']`? Why do you need to convert it to float?

Comment: It is either an integer or float. I need it for other calculations. You can ignore ``float`` here. Integer will suffice.

Comment: How expensive is `graph.get_edge_data(u, v)`? It may be worthwhile to make a memoized version of that function, since I presume it will get called on the same `(u, v)` pair multiple times. Of course that assumes that the inner lists are sharing nodes.

Comment: Side-note: `key=lambda inner_list: fun(inner_list)` is a slower, pointlessly verbose way to spell `key=fun`. And there is no need to slice the first argument to `zip`; `zip` stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted, so `zip(path[:-1], path[1:])` can avoid an unnecessary slice while behaving identically with `zip(path, path[1:])`. Also, a minor optimization: On Python 2, always use `itertools.izip` (or equivalently, replace `zip` using `from future_builtins import zip`) to avoid an unnecessary temporary `list` when you just need to iterate the zipped output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you need to use a sorting algorithm that allows you to parallelize the problem. A nice straightforward algorithm is merge sort. That would allow you to split the data, sort the parts, and then merge them in a final, single-threaded sort. However, that could lead to calculating the keys twice unless you cache the values.